# Software to monitor a CPU usage and RAM usage of a process?

Tags: windows, software-rec, display

Software to monitor the CPU usage and RAM usage of a process (e.g. chrome.exe)?

Windows operating system.

Comment: Is there something you don't like about windows built-in processes tab in the task manager?

Comment: Because Window 's task manager cannot keep trace for a particular process

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The standard answer is [Sysinternal's Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx).  Don't forget to check out the graphs as well as the individual process property dialogues.

Comment: Yes , it works.But seems that it cannot show the ram usage in the graph

Comment: You'll probably have to resort to two different apps to do this

Comment: Process Explorer will show per process RAM graphs: either add the memory history column to the main display or the "Performance Graph" tab of the process properties dialogue.