# Program to monitor processes with high CPU usage and memory consumption in realtime

Tags: memory, process, cpu-usage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Software to monitor a CPU usage and RAM usage of a process?](https://superuser.com/questions/202686/software-to-monitor-a-cpu-usage-and-ram-usage-of-a-process)

I need a program that monitors the top five (or similar) processes according to CPU usage and memory consumption. There is a perfect Windows gadget for me called Top Process but like any other Vista/7 gadget it uses WMI to collect data about CPU and memory usage, and that is slow and often inaccurate, especially in situations when CPU load is high.

[image]

There are lots of CPU usage programs and gauges but I didn't find any that will show load for process. I want to have this program always visible, just like a Vista gadget.

Comment: You may never find something that looks as pretty/gadget-y as you'd like, yet still real-time. :)

Comment: yes, but I want to have this info visible all the time, just like the gadgets but I would like it to work also ;)