# Measuring usage of RAM?

Tags: windows-xp, memory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Software to monitor a CPU usage and RAM usage of a process?](https://superuser.com/questions/202686/software-to-monitor-a-cpu-usage-and-ram-usage-of-a-process)

I am looking for a program (that is free) to measure the usage of RAM when the program is running. I am using Windows XP. If there is a duplicate question here I have missed it please point me the right direction.

Note: This question: [Software to monitor a CPU usage and RAM usage of a process?](https://superuser.com/questions/202686/software-to-monitor-a-cpu-usage-and-ram-usage-of-a-process) is close but I cannot see RAM usage or am I missing something?

The program that would be the best would be able to track RAM usage from when launched. Then I could use a programs like I normally do and see the RAM usage over the entire process.

Comment: Look in the "Working Set" column; that's the memory usage. Also... what's wrong with the normal Task Manager? (Press `Ctrl+Shift+Esc`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sysinternals' [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) will do what you want.  If you look for the Working Set column, that will reflect the pages the process has mapped into memory.